# WPF - Change DataContext during a Property is changing causes wrong binding

Tags: wpf, binding, datacontext

I have a textBox bound on a counter which is incremented quickly (each 10 millisecond).

```
<TextBox  Text="{Binding CounterInc.Counter}"/>
```

CounterInc is a class which increment the Counter property in a thread.

When I affect an other object the CounterInc property:
(To be sure to see difference between the both counters, first counter is circular between 1 and 100 and second counter is circular between 1000 and 1100)

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (flag)
            CounterInc = FirstCounterInc;
        else
            CounterInc = SecondCounterInc;

        flag = !flag;
    }
```

The TexBox continue to display the value of the old Counter.
If I stop counter incrementation before to reaffect CounterInc property, I don't have problem, textBox display the new counter value.
It seems that binding failed to attach to correct property propertyChanged event if the currentValue bound is changing.
Note that the behavior is equally correct if counter incrementation is slower (500 ms).
Have you ever seen this problem, and the exact reason of this problem.
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: CounterInc both start new Threads?

Comment: Yes, it's a new thread each time

Answer (score 0):

The default binding for all bindings in WPF is OneTime.  Change the binding to be OneWay

```
Binding CounterInc.Counter, Mode=OneWay
```

And make sure that the NotifyPropertyChanged is being correctly called for the CounterInc.Counter property.

Comment: Firstly, it's wrong, default binding for all bindings in WPF is not OneTime. Secondly,the propertyChanged event is correctly called because the value is updated, but comes from the bad dataContext property... Did you read my question ??